# Displays only the last row in foreach statement

Tags: php, foreach

```
          if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $slNo   =   $row->sl_no;
            //echo "</br>";
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM main_stock_outward WHERE product_id='$slNo' AND request_id='$requestId'";
            //echo "</br>";
            $query1     = $this->db->query($sql1);
            if (!($query1->num_rows() > 0)) 
            {
                echo "hi";
                echo $sql2  =   "SELECT a.sl_no,a.product_name,a.barcode,b.request_qty,b.deliver FROM stock_product a, stock_request b WHERE b.pos_id='$posNum' AND b.ordered_date like '$requestIssueDate%' AND b.request_id='$requestId' AND a.sl_no='$slNo' AND b.deliver='0' AND a.barcode=b.product_barcode ORDER BY request_qty DESC";
                $query2     = $this->db->query($sql2);
                //return $query2;
                $arr_data['query3']=array('sales'   => $query2);
                //$query3   = array(
                //  'sales' => $query2);
            }
        }
        print_r($arr_data['query3']);
        return $query2;
    }
```

as shown in the code again.I am able to display only the last row it is not able to display the rows ?

Comment: I think you should use JOINs instead of somehow nested SQL queries.

Comment: thats not my question is... i am able to get all the values.. the problem is not able to display all of them... just displaying the last row

Comment: That's why I commented instead of answering your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
 if($query->num_rows()>0)
{
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $slNo   =   $row->sl_no;
        //echo "</br>";
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM main_stock_outward WHERE product_id='$slNo' AND request_id='$requestId'";
        //echo "</br>";
        $query1     = $this->db->query($sql1);
        if (!($query1->num_rows() > 0)) 
        {
            echo "hi";
            echo $sql2  =   "SELECT a.sl_no,a.product_name,a.barcode,b.request_qty,b.deliver FROM stock_product a, stock_request b WHERE b.pos_id='$posNum' AND b.ordered_date like '$requestIssueDate%' AND b.request_id='$requestId' AND a.sl_no='$slNo' AND b.deliver='0' AND a.barcode=b.product_barcode ORDER BY request_qty DESC";
            $query2     = $this->db->query($sql2);
            //return $query2;
            $arr_data['query3']**[]** =array('sales'   => $query2);
            //$query3   = array(
            //  'sales' => $query2);
        }
    }
    print_r($arr_data['query3']);
    return $query2;
}
```

you have missed to make the array, I have modified the line -  $arr_data['query3'] =array('sales'   => $query2); as $arr_data['query3'][] =array('sales'   => $query2);

I think your problem will solve by this.

Comment: Array ( [query3] => Array ( [sales] => CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #29 [result_id] => Resource id #206 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 1 ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing it wrong. You are assigning every result to the same variable.
Try this instead:

```
$arr_data[]=array('sales'   => $query2);
```

and the:

```
print_r($arr_data);
```